# как исключить распространение стиля под определенным селектором?

Tags: css, less

html:

```
    <div class="active">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="diactive">
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="cont">
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="cont">
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="cont">
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>                

    </div>
```

кейс:
есть класс`active`, в котором всем элементам должны навешиваться заданные мной стили. НО не должны навешиваться внутри блока с классом `diactive`

что-то подобное, но это не работает:

```
.active *:not(.diactive) .item {
            border: .2px solid red;
        }
```

как корректно задать правило?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если рассматривать именно тот вариант вёрстки, который вы указали, то работать будет так:

```css
.active .item {
    border: .2px solid red;
}

.active .diactive .item {
    border: .2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="active">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="diactive">
            <div class="item">diactive 1</div>
            <div class="item">diactive 2</div>
            <div class="item">diactive 3</div>
            <div class="item">diactive 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
            <div class="item">active 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
            <div class="item">active 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
            <div class="item">active 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Либо же, если взять за основу приведённое вами описание стилей, то можно сделать так:

```css
.active *:not(.diactive) .item {
    border: .2px solid red;
}

.active .diactive .item {
    border: .2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="active">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="diactive">
            <div class="item">diactive 1</div>
            <div class="item">diactive 2</div>
            <div class="item">diactive 3</div>
            <div class="item">diactive 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
            <div class="item">active 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
            <div class="item">active 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
            <div class="item">active 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Есть ещё один вариант, который, возможно, вам подойдёт.
Однако использовать такие селекторы я бы рекомендовал с большой осторожностью, так как сами по себе они являются не самыми очевидными, а результат их использования очень сильно зависит от структуры ваших узлов:

```css
.active * ~ :not(.diactive) > * {
    border: .2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="active">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="diactive">
            <div class="item">diactive 1</div>
            <div class="item2">diactive 2</div>
            <div class="item3">diactive 3</div>
            <div class="item4">diactive 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
            <div class="item">active 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
            <div class="item">active 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
            <div class="item">active 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

На самом же деле, хоть играть с селекторами и весело, но всё же в таких ситуациях хочется предложить пересмотреть концепцию приложения, в котором возникла потребность, описанная в вопросе.
Возможно (скорее всего), существуют более простые способы достижения цели, стоящей перед вами.

Например, самый простой вариант - указывать класс `active` явно для каждого блока:

```css
.active {
    border: .2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="active item">active 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="item">diactive 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="active item">active 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Не бойтесь ставить под сомнения готовые структуры и решения. Экспериментируйте и у вас обязательно получиться!

Удачи!

Comment: Дело в том, что стили у блоков внутри  .diactive неизвестны. Они будут разные

Comment: @IlyaNikulin вы имеете в виду, что внутри блока с классом `diactive` могут находиться блоки с другими классами, а не только `item` - я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @IlyaNikulin я добавил ещё один вариант, попробуйте

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот вариант:

```
.active .item {
   /* Ваш стиль */
}

.active .item .diactive {
     border: .2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал так >>

```
.active {
background-color: green;
color: orange;
}

.active .diactive .item {
background-color: red;
color: black;
}



 <div class="active">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="diactive">
            <div class="item">d</div>
            <div class="item">f</div>
            <div class="item">g</div>
            <div class="item">h</div>
        </div>

        <div class="cont">
            <div class="item">2</div>
        </div>

        <div class="cont">
            <div class="item">5</div>
        </div>

        <div class="cont">
            <div class="item">6</div>
        </div>                

</div>
```